# How to regulate voltage from marine battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, 12v, lead-acid

I have a telescope with a number of components that run on 12vdc.

I want to create some sort of power regulator to supply power to my components without frying anything. Is there some kind of voltage regulator i can put between the marine battery and my components to make sure nothing happens to them? I could put a power inverter in to the battery and then have 12vdc plugs plugged into that, but that seems like a wasted effort.

I just need to create some kind of block that will do the typical 9v/12v barrel connectors to a reliable power source.

Comment: Have you looked at the input specifications for your equipment? Equipment is usually specified with an input range of volts.

Comment: just says 12 vdc on the supply

Comment: if you want to regulate an exact 12v, search amazon for "buck boost" and grab a cheap module powered by an XL6009. Make sure to dial it in to 12.00v with a multi meter before connecting it up, or splurge on a fixed 12v output model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an appliance rating simply says 12V with no tolerance mentioned, it usually expects the range of a lead-acid battery in a car.

This is at least 10.8V .. 14.8V and usually wider.

From what I know about the telescopes, their internal components (cpus, servos, screens, etc) internally run on 5V or even lower (modern digital electronics is generally 3.3V or less), so it has its internal convertors that take care to stabilize whatever the other components need.

Using DC-DC convertors to stabilize the voltage will not necessarily bring you a better experience:

1. How much exact your 12V needs to be? It is already within 10% (without a charger connected) or within 20% (with a charger in parallel). How much do you lose in the cables? Quite a few 12V-labeled car-powered things actually run better at 13.5 or 14.0V (the voltage of a car battery with the engine running). E.g. phone/tablet/laptop chargers.
2. The convertor will have its loses. Your battery will deplete faster. Depending on the load profile, it may be as fast as twice faster, even with a high-quality convertor.
3. The electrical noise. A lead-acid battery is quite silent. A dc-dc convertor will bring a great variety of frequencies leaking to the load. E.g. camera powered off the same convertor may get dust-like noise or moires in the pictures.

---

In short, don't dive into complex electronics.

Use appropriate connectors. Twisted wires are for the brave.

Use fuses (this is important, lead-acid batteries are impressively powerful when unintentionally shorted).

Take care about the polarity.

Think about the voltage stabilization if and only if something works unacceptably AND you know it is not because of an over-depleted battery.

Comment: Oh yes, lots of power in lead-acid batteries - I have welded with them :) good for a quick fix in the middle of a field...

Answer (score 0):

If the marine battery is not used to power anything else, then I would not bother with a regulator. It'll be just about the cleanest supply you can get, and the long-term voltage drift due to discharge is inconsequential. Local bulk capacitors plugged into the power inputs of any motor drive boards will serve to AC-bypass the series impedance of the battery circuit.

Otherwise, you'd need a buck-boost converter module that can take input between 11V and 15V (at lest, it can have a wider range), and outputs 12V. You'd also need to filter the noisy output of such a buck-boost module well.

Comment: Under normal condition's, what you stated about the voltage range is true.  But transients on the 12V bus can easily exceed 100V in the case of an infrequent, non-standard event such as a load dump.  In the case of automotive electronics, this is one of the most stressing requirements to meet.

Comment: That said, if his telescope is the only thing on the battery (OP wasn't specific here), then I agree that's he's OK with just the battery.

Comment: i think the output from most any consumer-facing buck/boost module fed by a battery will be cleaner than most any telescope OEM's wall wart's output.